# What's the reason of the following JavaScript syntax when using closures?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, closures

Studying about closures, I looked at the Developer's Mozilla article about it and saw the code below:

```
var counter = (function() {
  var privateCounter = 0;
  function changeBy(val) {
    privateCounter += val;
  }

  return {
    increment: function() {
      changeBy(1);
    },

    decrement: function() {
      changeBy(-1);
    },

    value: function() {
      return privateCounter;
    }
  };
})();

console.log(counter.value());  // 0.

counter.increment();
counter.increment();
console.log(counter.value());  // 2.

counter.decrement();
console.log(counter.value());  // 1.
```

I'm confused about how the function is attributed to the variable `counter`, because the function is initially envolved by those parentheses, and after all, there are also two unreaseble parentheses together... I just wondered, what's the reason of that syntax? I certainly would do:

```
var counter = function() {
  var privateCounter = 0;
  function changeBy(val) {
    privateCounter += val;
  }

  return {
    increment: function() {
      changeBy(1);
    },

    decrement: function() {
      changeBy(-1);
    },

    value: function() {
      return privateCounter;
    }
  };
};
```

But then I got the error

> Uncaught TypeError: counter.value is not a function

When I do `console.log(counter.value());`

Can someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking at is an Immediately Invoked Function Expression or IIFE. This code is creating a function, then immediately calling that function, then assigning the *return value* of the function to `counter`. So `counter` isn't a function, it's an object with three properties: `increment`, `decrement`, and `value`.

The reason that they used an IIFE was to make what's essentially a private variable. `privateCounter` is only in scope to other code inside that function, which means only `increment`, `decrement`, and `value` can access it.

If they didn't care about making the variable private, the equivalent code would be:

```
var publicCounter = 0;
function changeBy(val) {
  publicCounter += val;
}

var counter = {
  increment: function() {
    changeBy(1);
  },
  decrement: function() {
    changeBy(-1);
  },
  value: function() {
    return publicCounter;
  }
}
```